I can't understand the definition of the language of NFA
I'm reading "INTRODUCTION TO Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation" by Hopcroft, Ullman and can't understand the definition of the language of NFA.
It says:
$$L(A)=\{w| \hat{\delta}(q_0,w) \cap F = \varnothing \}  $$
where $L$ - language, $w$ - string, $\hat{\delta}$ - extend the transition function, $q_0$ - start state, $F$ - set of final states.
Why intersection of those sets is empty set?
In example of NFA which accepts strings that end with $01$ we have $\{q_0, q_2\}$ end set which contains $q_2 \in F$. Therefore, if NFA accept a string, its set of $\hat{\delta}(q_0,w)$ must have a non-empty intersection with F. Where am I wrong?


Ok, I found the problem. It's incorrect translation of 2nd edition into russian language. I found 3rd one in english and here definition is correct, where $\hat{\delta}(q_0,w) \cap F \neq \varnothing$
